# Is there an adverb for "ungodly"?

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives, adverbs, dictionaries

All dictionaries listed *ungodly* only as an adjective. *Ungodlily* was listed on [Word Hippo](https://www.wordhippo.com/what-is/the-adverb-for/ungodly.html), but I'm not so sure if it's reliable. So, is there an adverb for *ungodly*, and if so, what is it? *Ungodlily* sounds a bit awkward and clunky.

Here's the sentence in question: *They were [ungodlily] outnumbered.* I don't think *ungodly* would work here (at least as an adjective).

Comment: Please use this in a sentence. And show us why *in an ungodly way* isn't good enough.

Comment: Of course @tchrist, will do.

Comment: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=ungodly_ADV%2Cungodlily_ADV&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cungodly_ADV%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cungodlily_ADV%3B%2Cc0m

Comment: If you look at the definition of [*ungodly*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ungodly), and if you don't want to rephrase the sentence, you can simply use a synonymous adverb. (In the the example sentence, *outrageously* seems like a good one.)

Comment: Taking Jason's lead and looking at [synonyms for ungodly](https://www.thesaurus.com/browse/ungodly), I come up with "corruptly", "godlessly", "indecently", "profanely", "sinfully", "wickedly", "impiously", "appallingly", etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The OED has an entry for ***ungodlily***. There are no examples more recent than 1860, but the ones provided are as follows:

> 583   J. Field Godly Exhortation sig. Cjv   Being thus vngodlilie
>   assembled, to so vnholy a spectacle.
>
> 1645   E. Pagitt Heresiogr. 54   Ungodlily alledging the..Scripture.
>
> 1674   Govt. Tongue 114   'Tis but an ill essay of that reverence and
>   godly fear, to use that very gospel so irreverently and ungodlily as
>   men now do.
>
> 1860   E. B. Pusey Minor Prophets 413   Israel..slaying ungodlily Him
>   who was by nature His Begotten Son.

Comment: That's because there is no data after 1924, when it was last updated. The word could well be obsolete now.

Comment: @AndrewLeach What exactly do you mean by "obsolete". Here we have an OP who wants to use the word - suggesting to me it cannot be obsolete. Are you proposing that no one should ever use an "obsolete" word.

Comment: I'm not suggesting that *per se,* but things change in a hundred years. I think you'll find far more uses of *ungodly* as an adverb these days.

Comment: @AndrewLeach As regards the adjective, it is mostly the OED sense 3 (colloquial) of *ungodly* which is used today. It is mainly used as an intensifier. It is rare to hear anyone use it meaning "un-god-like". In that sense *ungodly* doesn't really work as an adverb, and the examples the OED gives of its adverbial use are of the original meaning. The essential point here is not just that the adverb has disappeared, but the original meaning of the adjective too.

Answer (score 0):

Out of my above list, in the given context, I would nominate

**appallingly**

Based on the adjective [appalling](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/appalling) [Macmillian]:

> very unpleasant and shocking

I will note that I choose this term because, in the OP's example context, "ungodly" is being used in the sense of "excessive" or "unreasonable".  Per [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/ungodly), definitions 2 & 3:

> 2. adjective [ADJECTIVE noun] If you refer to a time as an ungodly hour,
>      you are emphasizing that it is very early in the morning. [emphasis]
>      ...at the ungodly hour of 4.00am.
> 3. adjective [ADJECTIVE noun] If you refer to the amount or volume of something as ungodly, you mean that it is excessive or unreasonable.

"Ungodly" is used quite frequently in this sense (at least in the US).

[Houston Press](https://www.houstonpress.com/news/a-freeway-traffic-primer-for-houstonians-10710903):

> Hey, welcome to Houston! You'll love it here...once we get to October.
>   But, there are some things you should know, particularly about
>   Houston's ungodly traffic.

[UPI](https://www.upi.com/Archives/1984/09/10/A-brutal-heat-wave-that-turned-Southern-California-into/6709463636800/):

> 'Last week we had the blast furnace heat, but today we have the
>   ungodly humidity and it feels worse.

Comment: What became of the godless? Did they retreat beyond the pall? Heaven forbid!

Comment: I'm a little curious as to why this answer is being down-voted.